# linux find command to move files

Tags: linux

I have a folder with lots of images,I want to move all images which  filename contains "cover" and size is bigger than 100K to */root/img*. Below command can move all the files that filename contains "cover" but without size condition.My questions is how to combine with condition that image's size is bigger than 100K.thank you!

```
find . -name '*cover*' -exec mv '{}' /root/img  \;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
find . -name '*cover*' -size +100k -exec mv '{}' /root/img \;
```

This command will move any file that contains the name "cover" and is greater than 100K.

Comment: what does `{}` mean?

Comment: {} gets replaced with the file name.

Answer (score 1):

You want the `-size` predicate.

Comment: how to combine with -name? could you show me full command? thanks